# INSTALL_ASSET functionality from google

Tags: android

Is there any code or reference like how to use `INSTALL_ASSET` for remote installation of application.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `INSTALL_ASSET` in the Android SDK, nor does `INSTALL_ASSET` appear to be in the Android open source code.

Comment: then is it possible to build app which can be remotely installed?

Comment: @Nnj: Not really. You can create an app that can download and request to install other apps, though the user will get a chance to confirm their installation. You certainly cannot force your app to be installed on random devices remotely.

Comment: In other words the [INSTALL_ASSET](https://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2010/06/25/remote-kill-and-install-on-google-android/) is not documented in the sdk and implemented in the non-opensource-part of android